# How to know if my pet emperor scorpion is pregnant?

Tags: exotic-pets, scorpions, pregnancy

I bought a female Emperor Scorpion. I have heard that they have long gestation periods and are often pregnant when bought. How can I find out if my scorpion is pregnant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Look at Opisthoma of the scorpion.

See the ventral (meaning belly side) and the dorsal (meaning upper side or back side). On both sides there is a series of carapace, meaning hard shell. The one on the ventral side is called sternite and the one on the dorsal side is called tergite.

There are about 7 carapace joined one after another. They are joined by a whitish membrane called pleural membrane.

The carapaces will be extended a little bit and pleural membrane will be exposed. As such you will see a little bit of white space between each carapaces.

See the below picture -

[image]

Look at the exposed whitish pleural membrane.

This is the sure sign that your scorpion is pregnant.